# Can I use firebase with my apps user account requirements

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework

I am looking for clarification on what firebase can and can't do. Or even should and shouldn't be used for.

**My use case**
I have an ionic mobile app which requires the user to login. The apps user will input data anywhere from once a week to multiple times a day. This information must be stored locally on the device and, through a paid option, in the cloud. The information to be stored will be mostly text but with some amount of videos and images.

The user should be able to access this data via a website or the mobile app. They should be able to share it with specified users, manually or automatically.

There will be two types of user. One will have access to only their own data and the other will have access to multiple users data. The later will be able to run operations on this data to get graphs and comparisons etc.

That is 99% of the functionality the app will need from the backend. My question boils down to can firebase do the above or would I be better off with the likes of Heroku. My main reason for thinking firebase is its great support in the ionic community and its high recommendations.

Thanks for the help

Comment: "This information must be stored locally on the device and, through a paid option, in the cloud" Firebase doesn't have an option to store data locally-only through its API, all data you `push()`/`set()`/`update()` will be synchronized to its servers when a connection is available. So if you decide to use Firebase, you will either have to let go of that requirement or implement you own local-storage API.

Comment: Can I not use firebase alongside the local storage that ionic provides?